# How to click a button inside an info window with ngMap and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ng-map

I used ngMap with AngularJS to display marker and info window.
The info window is used with customized template and HTML.
However, when I used a button and click event inside the info window, it didn't work.
I tried $compile and addListener but it failed to work too.

```
var infoTemplate = `<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="$ctrl.myFunction();">Add</button>`
this.markerCustomTemplate = $sce.trustAsHtml(marker.infoTemplate);
```

```html
<info-window id="marker-info-custom-template">
    <div ng-non-bindable="">
        <span ng-bind-html="$ctrl.markerCustomTemplate"></span>
    </div>
</info-window>
```

Sample code: https://plnkr.co/edit/mBeJb7EErrkts6Fq?preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-bind-compile instead of ng-bind-html.

Don't forget to include angular-bind-compile.min.js in your project.

```
<span ng-bind-compile="$ctrl.markerCustomTemplate"></span>
```